# CSS : float based on height ( column wise)

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a menu in which the list items are floating should be column wise (line by line) instead of row wise ( side by side). for example,

Currently I've menu like this,

[image: current menu]

and I want to change the layout like this,

[image: wanna change like this]

I'm using below code for list items,

```
.mnu-third li  {
    width:150px;
    height:15px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

Here, if the list items reached certain height limit of menu, then it should be started from the next column.

Please do help...

EDIT : [Here is my  code](http://jsfiddle.net/vtajZ/612/)
Goto top category and sub - sub categories...

Comment: Please provide a working demo so we can help you

Comment: Add display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap;

Answer (score 1):

Just add CSS columns to your `ul` and control it with `height`. Nothing more required.

```css
ul {
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-columns: 3; -moz-columns: 3; columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>Four</li><li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li><li>Seven</li><li>Eight</li><li>Nine</li><li>Ten</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: [CSS Columns browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn). It's interesting that aside from Opera mini, the only browsers that support the standard `columns` property is IE10 / 11.

Comment: Yup @misterManSam. IE is splurging on standards lately! Wondering how much more time will it take to get rid of vendor prefixes and have things standardized!

Answer (score 0):

use below css

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Change height and width according to your requirement.

http://jsfiddle.net/3orkpyoh/1/